# itext Rotate pdf document but not image

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am using itext library in which i have to put image which scale properly in landscape mode . However if i changes the page to landscape mode ,the images which holds there also gets rotated . i don't want that.And if i rotate the image it will behave differently ,it will not rotate from centre.

[image]

However ,what i want the image should not rotate ,and it should appear as follows
[image]

here is my code

```
Document document=new Document();
            try {
                File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"mypdfimage.pdf");
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
                document.open();
                Image image = null;
                try {
                    image = Image.getInstance (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/image.jpg");
                    int identation=0;
                     //Rectangle rectangle=document.getPageSize();


                     Rotation rotation=new Rotation();

                     pdfwriter.setPageEvent(rotation);

                     //image.scalePercent(scalerX, scalerY);
                     //PdfDictionary pageDict=null;
                    // pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(90));
                     //pdfwriter.addPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE, PdfPage.LANDSCAPE);


                     image.scaleToFit(PageSize.A4.getWidth() - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin(), PageSize.A4.getHeight() - document.topMargin() - document.bottomMargin());
                     // image.setRotationDegrees(90);
                     // image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                     document.add(image);               
                document.close();


                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        public  class Rotation extends PdfPageEventHelper
         {




         @Override
         public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
         writer.addPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE,PdfPage.LANDSCAPE);
         }


         }
```

Comment: Who told you to rotate a page in a page event???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rotating the page the wrong way. You probably took an example that was written in answer to a question asking how to rotate the page *and* its content. That is the *exception*. If you follow the *normal* examples on how to rotate a page, the page will be rotated, but not the image.

Please take a look at the [ImageOnRotatedPage](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/images/ImageOnRotatedPage) example:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Image img = Image.getInstance(IMAGE);
    img.scaleToFit(770, 523);
    float offsetX = (770 - img.getScaledWidth()) / 2;
    float offsetY = (523 - img.getScaledHeight()) / 2;
    img.setAbsolutePosition(36 + offsetX, 36 + offsetY);
    document.add(img);
    document.close();
}
```

As you can see, I create a rotated A4 page by using the `rotate()` method:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
```

I also scale the image so that it fits the page and I calculate an offset so that it is nicely centered on the page. See [cardiogram.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/cardiogram.pdf):

[image]

This looks exactly the way you want it to look and you don't need to resort to using page events and changing the page dictionary.

Comment: thanks it worked . i was using Pageeventhelper to rotate page .

Comment: float scalerX = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin()
                        - document.rightMargin() - identation) / image.getWidth()) * 100;


                float scalerY=(( document.getPageSize().getHeight()-document.topMargin()
                        -document.bottomMargin()-identation)/image.getHeight())*100;

Comment: Above code helped me to place exactly the way i wanted.